# golang why does field not existed in go struct still present after marshaling said struct to json

Tags: json, go

in golang, I am modifying a json by unmarshaling it to a struct with only the fields I need then marshaling it again to json to keep only the fields I need

it works great with

```
i := DBBatch{}
```

to declare the interface and output json only have what I want

```
{
    "field_to_keep": "XXXXX",
    "field_to_keep2": "26400527"
}
```

but with the full declare syntax the output still has the extra field but as far as I understand it is just syntax sugar that does the same thing, what might explain the difference in output?

```
`var i interface{} = DBBatch{}`
```

output

```
{
    "field_to_delete": "whynotdeleted",
    "field_to_keep": "XXXXX",
    "field_to_keep2": "26400527"
}
```

this example shows `var i interface{} = DBBatch{}` declaration and does not remove the unwanted field
https://go.dev/play/p/u7GQzqBma7v

but with `i := DBBatch{}` declaration the extra field is removed?
https://go.dev/play/p/1sOEPtnIpsc

could you please explain what I am missing here? thanks

working code that does not remove `"field_to_delete": "whynotdeleted"`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type DBBatch struct {
    FieldtoKeep  string `json:"field_to_keep"`
    FieldtoKeep2 string `json:"field_to_keep2"`
}

func main() {
    jsonBatch := `{"field_to_keep":"XXXXX","field_to_keep2":"26400527","field_to_delete":"whynotdeleted"}`
    var i interface{} = DBBatch{}
    //i := DBBatch{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBatch), &i); err != nil {
        log.Println("json UnMarshal from batch json failed")
        log.Println(err)
    }
    dbJsonBatch, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("json Marshal from batch json failed")
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println("json Marshal from maps of key string and value interface to batch json for insert to DB")
    log.Println(string(dbJsonBatch))
    pp, _ := json.MarshalIndent(i, "", "    ")
    log.Println(string(pp))
}
```

Comment: Don't use pointers to interfaces, especially if the value stored in the interface is a non pointer, the result will almost never be what one would expect. Do the following instead: https://go.dev/play/p/LFx4ya3mXSl

Comment: What happens is that your non-pointer `DBBatch` instance gets completely thrown out because it's useless since it's a copy with no outside observer. See https://go.dev/play/p/KX5scKJwYV2

Comment: can you please elaborate? so with i := DBBatch{}, i is a pointer to DBBatch structure, but with var i interface{} = DBBatch{}, i is a pointer to interface then is also initialized to a pointer to DBBatch structure? what is the difference I am missing

Comment: `i := DBBatch{}`: `i` is not a pointer, but the `&i` expression generates a pointer (type `*DBBatch`) and that's what you are passing to the unmarshaler. `var i inteface{} = DBBatch{}`: `i` is not a pointer, it is an interface value that stores a `DBBatch` instance, the expression `&i` generates a pointer (type `*interface{}`) and that's what you're passing to the unmarshaler. `*interface{}` and `*DBBatch` are two fundamentally different types, so the fact that they produce different behaviour should not be a surprise.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, so with both method of declaration, the type of i is DBBatch, as shown in the print statement, but after the unmarshaling the first one type of i changes to map[string]interface {} but second method i stays as DBBatch. What is causing this? if the type is correct immediately after declaration why it would behave that way afterwards?  fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) // type is DBBatch...

Comment: @mkopriva, thanks, that makes sense, just one more confusion, for "it is an interface value that stores a DBBatch instance", so = does not really work with interface type then? or I am just wondering if I could still use a full declaration syntax and achieve the same thing

Comment: *"so with both method of declaration, the type of i is DBBatch"* -- no, not exactly, `fmt`'s parameter type is the empty interface itself, so every argument you pass to it (interface or not) will be wrapped (or "repackaged") into the empty interface. Given this fact, it would make no sense for `fmt` to print the **static** type of its arguments, because then it would always print `interface{}` for every single argument, no exceptions... That's why `fmt` instead "unpacks" the interface and prints the **dynamic** type of the argument.

Comment: So the two `i` variables have two different **static** types, even if `fmt` shows only one type.

Comment: *"so = does not really work with interface type then?"* the `=` has no relevance here. You can do `var i inteface{} = DBBatch{}` (normal _variable declaration_ with explicit type) or `i := inteface{}(DBBatch{})` (this is a _short variable declaration_ with a _conversion_ on the right hand side), and you can do `var i DBBatch = DBBatch{}` or `var i = DBBatch{}` (normal _variable declaration_ with _implicit type_ resolved from the RHS) or `i := DBBatch{}` (_short variable declaration_).

Comment: thanks, I was not aware that go has both dynamic and static types, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337403  I am assuming this is what you are talking about and the right direction to read more about it?

Comment: The only thing I'm confident enough to recommend is the [official spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec). You don't have to read it from start to finish, just go there, scan the page for the thing you want to learn about, e.g. "dynamic type", then read every paragraph where it appears, and you're bound to gain some insight.

Comment: `var i interface{} = DBBatch{}
 fmt.Printf("Type of variable i: %T\n", i)
 fmt.Printf("Type of variable &i: %T\n", &i)` Will give you an insight.