# How read interface value having address of struct

Tags: go

I have variable with data type `interface{}` and passing address of struct to it. now I unable read fields from interface

code as below:

```
type UserData struct {
    UserID string `json:"user_id"`
    UserName string `json:"user_name"`
}

type Result struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}

var res Result
res.Data = &UserData
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"status": "success", "data": {"user_id":15,"user_name":"abc"}}`), &res)
fmt.Println(res.Data) //working fine
fmt.Println(res.Data.UserName) //getting error: type interface{} has no field or method UserName
```

if I use `res.Data.UserName` getting error

How to read struct fields from interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting to compare this with [golang why does field not existed in go struct still present after marshaling said struct to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76284655/golang-why-does-field-not-existed-in-go-struct-still-present-after-marshaling-sa). At first I thought they are the same. But it turns out that they are not.

For this question, `res.Data` holds a value of type `*UserData`. So a simple type assertion will work.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type UserData struct {
    UserID   string `json:"user_id"`
    UserName string `json:"user_name"`
}

type Result struct {
    Status string      `json:"status"`
    Data   interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    var res Result
    res.Data = &UserData{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"status": "success", "data": {"user_id":15,"user_name":"abc"}}`), &res)
    fmt.Println(res.Data)
    fmt.Println(res.Data.(*UserData).UserName)
}
```

The following demo is a merge of @mkopriva's two demos, and it shows the difference:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type DBBatch struct {
    FieldtoKeep  string `json:"field_to_keep"`
    FieldtoKeep2 string `json:"field_to_keep2"`
}

func main() {
    jsonBatch := `{"field_to_keep":"XXXXX","field_to_keep2":"26400527","field_to_delete":"whynotdeleted"}`
    var i interface{} = DBBatch{}
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) // type is DBBatch
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBatch), &i); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) // type is not DBBatch anymore, instead it's map[string]any

    i = &DBBatch{}
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) // type is *DBBatch
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBatch), &i); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) // type is *DBBatch
}
```

The output is:

```
main.DBBatch
map[string]interface {}
*main.DBBatch
*main.DBBatch
```